# Geodesic routes in gmaps4rails

Tags: gmaps4rails

I can currently draw polylines using gmaps4rails in Rails but I'd like to draw them as geodesic paths. According to the Google Map documentation this should be as simple as adding "geodesic: true" to the options [(link)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry). Below is my current implementation that doesn't work but simply draws a straight line on the map. Is there a correct way of setting this option in gmaps4rails or is this not currently supported?

In my controller:

```
@json_route = 
[
  [
    {'lng' =>  80.190262, 'lat' => 55.774252 },
    {'lng' => -66.118292, 'lat' => 38.466465 }
  ]
]

@gmaps_options = 
{
  :polylines => { "data" => @json_route.to_json, "options" => { "geodesic" => true }}
}
```

In my html page:

```
<%= gmaps(@gmaps_options) %>
```

Thank you!

Comment: please file an issue on github, I'll add this

Comment: Added to github, thanks!